# check a string for words in a mysql database. (realtime)

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, database

I have a mysql database where words are stored. Now I want to check a string to see if it contains one or more of the words from the database.

for example:

```
var desc = 'you are a stupid man';

db.connect((err) => {
    if(err){
        throw err;
    }
    console.log('Connected!');

    let sql = 'SELECT `word` FROM `words`';
    db.query(sql, (err, result) => {
        if(err){
            throw err;
        }
        if(desc.toLowerCase().includes(result)){
            console.log('Dont use words like {word*}');
        }
    });

});
```

*word / words that were found.

Actually I only have to store the words of the mysql database in an array or not? but I just can't figure out how it works.
Maybe it's something very simple that I just don't get into my mind.

The method must also allow that when I insert a new word into the database, it is also searched for, even without restarting the script

greetings, 
nih

Comment: You can use IN (mysql) to check for a match in an array of values, but you would need to format your desc into the format so it looks like ('you', 'are', 'a', 'stupid', 'man') - this can be achieved using desc.replace() function and some if's. I don't have time to write this out, hope you can use this to help. https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_replace.asp https://www.w3resource.com/mysql/comparision-functions-and-operators/in-function.php

Answer (score 0):

This is an interesting challenge to solve, it teaches you the separated nature of database and application.

Your script (if using a database), will automatically pull new records (using a query), so no worries about searching over all items. Unless you're storing results in a variable/cache, but I'd assume you're using a new query each time.

You could hold a table: `banned_words` with an ID and VARCHAR columns, then insert any new banned words there.

You could leverage MySQL here, and use the query:

```sql
SELECT * FROM words WHERE `word`='*{word}*'
```

**I'd read the answer in the comments, it's more specific to your question, using IN here would be a better choice if you have an array of strings**

This may not be the exact syntax (been a while since I've worked with SQL), however should point you in the right direction. Use your database where possible, you can directly use it to find the exact data you require (I.E does word exist?).

You *could* even just determine how many rows exist for using a similar query, avoiding the need to actually retrieve data. (if you're basically using a conditional, you don't need the data in a variable).